# Connect Business SQL Database to Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

We have a database within Azure, but this database is not an azure database... just an SQL database sat within azure. I am trying to use power automate (with a premium account) to connect directly to this database but I get the following error:

Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) clientRequestId: 7729dd1f-7ead-428d-a8c4-72e69cf122af

Can anyone advise whether this is a problem in my set up or a firewall issue, or setup within azure?... something seems to be stopping that connection that I cannot work out.

I have followed all the video content online... there is something I am missing in the security of the connection I'm sure